# How to apply a tag to CDK managed resource, but only when it is deployed

Tags: aws-cdk

Kia ora.

We have a very specific tagging specification for all our AWS resources at work. Obviously I can add "static" tags to all resources within the stack/app, like this:

```cs
var app = new App();
new MyStack(app, "MyStack", new StackProps
{
    // ...
});

// Required, "static" tags, as per our tagging specification
Tags.Of(app).Add("uuid", "unique-internal-identifier");
Tags.Of(app).Add("env.name", "testish");
Tags.Of(app).Add("managed:ownership:division", "Flibble");
Tags.Of(app).Add("managed:ownership:portfolio", "Flooble");
Tags.Of(app).Add("managed:ownership:product-group", "Wibble");
// ... and so on

app.Synth();
```

The way I understand the semantics of this is that the CDK is being told that the resources declared within the construct (`app`) are **required** to have these tags applied in order for the CDK's "model" to be considered consistent with the deployed resources in AWS. And so the applicable resources will be created/updated, and have the applicable tabs applied. If the "static" value of a tag is changed, then all constructs that have that tag applied will be redeployed during the "deploy" phase of the CDK.

There are, however, other tags that our tagging specification requires which contain more dynamic content. An example would be a git commit hash; or date/time of deployment. For these, we want to update the tags' values **if and only if** the CDK effects a change within AWS for any other reason. That is: the definition of the tag should not form part of the evaluation of the consistency of the CDK's "model"; but if the CDK makes any change to the affected resource, then a new value for the tag should be set.

How would I accomplish this? Is there an escape hatch in the "plan" stage of the CDK to exclude certain tags, but then have the tag values applied during a "deploy" stage?

Comment: I'm afraid there's nothing that CDK has to assist with this. `deploy` does `synth` first, the program cannot tell if a deploy will happen. That wouldn't help anyway, since `deploy` doesn't mean there are other non-tag changes. To clarify - AWS will not redeploy resources that have their tags changed, it'll only update the tags. As to the question itself - you'll have to write your own method of detecting change.

Comment: You could have a lambda-backed custom resource apply these dynamic tags, and pass it the hash of all the resource's properties, so a change to the resource would trigger an update of the CR, which would update the tag. This is rather hacky